# MAKEFILE,COMPILE,GCC and LINKING

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, embedded-linux

I am getting this error while running make file to link the .o files.
command is $make build PLATFORM=HOST or $make build PLATFORM=MSP432,both gives the same error.

```
gcc  main.o memory.o -DHOST   -g -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  -I../src/ -I../include/CMSIS/ -I../include/msp432/ -I../include/common/ -I../ -Wl,-Map=c1m2.map -L/usr/local/lib -T ../msp432p401r.lds -o c1m2.out
/usr/bin/ld: c1m2.out: Not enough room for program headers, try linking with -N
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:79: recipe for target 'c1m2.out' failed
make: *** [c1m2.out] Error 1
```

and my makefile script:

```
include sources.mk

# Platform Overrides

PLATFORM = HOST

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = armv7e-m
SPECS = nosys.specs

# Compiler Flags and Defines

# Conditional statements to choose the platform(host/msp432) else invalid platform message is diplayed.
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)
    CC = gcc 
    CFLAGS = -DHOST  
    LD = ld
else 
    CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
    CFLAGS = -DMSP432 -mcpu=$(CPU) -march=$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS)  -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 
    LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
endif


TARGET = c1m2
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map  -T ../msp432p401r.lds
CPPFLAGS = -g -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  $(INCLUDES)

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

pre = $(SRCS:.c=.i)

%.i : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -E -o $@

asem =$(SRCS:.c=.asm):

%.asm : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -S -o $@

.PHONY: build
build: all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET).out

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(pre) $(asem) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map
```

I have created this for running both in HOST and the given processor(MSP432),please don't bother poor formatting.

Comment: Does it help to follow the suggestion presented in the error message (to add `-N` to the link options)?

Comment: You might also try changing the `-g -O0` in your `CPPFLAGS` to `-Osize`.

Comment: Are you saying `-os` flag?. I used the `-os` flag and still getting the same error.@JohnBollinger

Comment: In case of `-N` it gives `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:77: recipe for target 'c1m2.out' failed
make: *** [c1m2.out] Error 1`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If compiling for host, why do you use a linker script for ARM?